# Spring AOP intercepting some Public Method but not other

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have placed and interceptor in my aspect class as

```
@Before("execution( * com.mycompany.a.service.weblab.b.doesTreatmentEqualsAndTrigger(..))"){
.........
}
```

this interceptor works fine but when i place this interceptor

```
@Before("execution( * mycompany.a.b.bsf.c.requestReply(..))"){
............
}
```

the code is not intercepted.

My aspect class is in `com.mycompany.x` package and both the function on which i am trying to place the interceptor are `public` as needed by spring AOP.

My `.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="no">
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean name="com.a.serviceInterceptor" class="com.mycompany.x.RequestSpecificServiceAspect"/>

</beans>
```

Why is the second function not getting intercepted? Is it because of the vastly different package since they don't have anything in common? If so then how i can resolve this ?

Comment: Not a spring bean, in the wrong context, internal method call. Just to name 3 things that can be wrong.

Comment: the problem was that this is not a spring bean. But just for understanding what is do you mean by wrong context?

Comment: AOP is only applied to beans in the same `ApplicationContext`. If you have multiple contexts (a `ContectLoaderLIstener` and `DispatcherServlet`) and you have defined AOP in the root one (`ContextLoaderListener`) that doesn't apply to the child context (`DispatcherServlet`).